# Poll to see how most people think a certain word (audio) is spelled

Tags: audio, survey

I would like to get a sense for how most people would spell a certain ambiguous (foreign) word, in order to know whether it's best to avoid it during an important event where people will be taking notes.

Where can I create a simple poll that includes an audio recording of said word, and where people can type in how they think the word is spelled? I could then look at the word frequency statistics and conclude whether on average people spell the word correctly or not.

I know services such as Amazon Turk exist to run simple online experiments, but this is so simple that I'm hoping a ready-made service (ideally free) exists, though I did not find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site seems to offer audio surveys that may suit your needs.

https://www.questionpro.com/features/audio.html

Looks like it's pretty straight forward to embed audio:

https://www.questionpro.com/help/audio-survey.html
[image]